# Byobu - send command to byobu tmux session from commandline (or bash/sh)

Tags: command-line, gnu-screen, tmux, byobu

I run a script which I would like to print the status to a byobu tmux session. So for example `print backup finished \n`. Is it possible to do this with the name of the byobu tmux window, which you can give/rename with `F8` ?

With screen (before) I did it like this: `screen -S $SCREEN_NAME -p 0 -X stuff "print backup finished.$(printf \\r)"`

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this would be to use tmux's command-prompt action.

With a running [Byobu](http://byobu.co) (or [tmux](http://manpg.es/tmux.1)) session, simply run:

```
tmux command-prompt -p "backup finished"
```

This will print the message, "backup finished", in the status line, and stay there until you hit "enter" to acknowledge it.

Note that it's not window specific, but that command can be session (client) specific.

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: kay, thanks. how do I make sure that it is send to the right session ? I have multiple tabs with different names.